PySide\Pyqt Unable to update QTableView - index (tuple) is perceived as a number
Simple table model. I'm trying to update one cell via spinbox. But the index passed is perceived as a number:
TypeError: descriptor 'index' for '...QAbstractTableModel' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object.
See the __handleSpinBox method at the bottom of the code. I tried to manipulate the method setData but nothing worked out. Another odd thing is that there is almost nothing about this error in Google search.
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QTableView, QApplication, QAbstractItemView, QSpinBox
from PySide6.QtGui import *
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import copy



class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, table):
        super(PandasModel, self).__init__()
        data = pd.DataFrame(table)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role: Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()  
            column = index.column() 
            self._data[row][column] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index)
            return True
        return False

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None


class MyTable(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, model:QAbstractTableModel, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
        self.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.model = model(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']))
        self.setModel(self.model)


class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setRange(-100, 100)
        self.spinBox.setValue(0)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.__handleSpinBox)
        self.pandasModel = PandasModel
        table = MyTable(PandasModel, [[0,0,0], [0,0,0]])
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.spinBox, 1)
        hbox.addWidget(table, 1)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

    def __handleSpinBox(self, value):
        self.pandasModel.setData(self.pandasModel.index(1,1), result, Qt.EditRole) #TypeError:
        # descriptor 'index' for 'PySide6.QtCore.QAbstractTableModel' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWidget()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())     


self.pandasModel is just a further reference to PandasModel, which is a class, not an instance. It's quite unclear what would be the point of referencing a class, but, in any case, its usage is wrong (as the type hinting in MyTable is). Even assuming you actually need to reference the class for some reason, you cannot use self.pandasModel like that. At the very least, use the table's model, but you need to create a persistent reference to it, as right now it's just a local variable. Also note that the role argument in setData() and headerData() should be optional.

There are reasons to define QTableView in a separate class. Only one cell changes (1,1).
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QTableView, Application, QAbstractItemView, QSpinBox
from PySide6.QtGui import *
import sys
import pandas as pd



externalData = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]

class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(PandasModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role: Qt.EditRole):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iat[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            return True
        return False

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None


class MyTable(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTable, self).__init__()
        self.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)


class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500,200)
        self.data = data
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setRange(-100, 100)
        self.spinBox.setValue(0)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.__handleSpinBox)
        self.model = PandasModel(self.data)
        self.table = MyTable()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.spinBox, 1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.table, 3)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

    def __handleSpinBox(self, value):
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(1, 1), value, Qt.EditRole)
        self.model.dataChanged.connect(self.table.update(self.model.index(1, 1)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWidget(externalData)
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())```


Sorry but I don't understand this. The problem of your question was related to the wrong usage of a reference (the class, instead of an instance). Using separated subclasses is not an issue, and wasn't the cause of the problem.

You are absolutely right. I took all circumstances  in my answer..
